# How to find length of an array inside another array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have object with multiple arrays inside one another just like hierarchy in javascript ,i just want to find the length of these array using loop for constructing organisation chart.

here is my javascript code

```js
var datasource = {
  'id': '1',
  'name': 'Nishang1',
  'title': 'DSN00001',
  'children': [{
      'id': '2',
      'name': 'Nishang2',
      'title': 'DSN00002'
    },
    {
      'id': '3',
      'name': 'Nishang3',
      'title': 'DSN00003',
      'children': [{
          'id': '4',
          'name': 'Nishang4',
          'title': 'DSN00004'
        },
        {
          'id': '5',
          'name': 'Nishang5',
          'title': 'DSN00005',
          'children': [{
              'id': '6',
              'name': 'Nishang6',
              'title': 'DSN00006'
            },
            {
              'id': '7',
              'name': 'Nishang7',
              'title': 'DSN00007',
              'children': [{
                  'id': '8',
                  'name': 'Nishang8',
                  'title': 'DSN00008'
                },
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
};
```

i want to find the length of every children.

i have find out length of 1 children array

console.log(datascource.children.length);          //output is 2

Comment: Hi, can you please share your expected output? Also, can you share your attempt for that?

Comment: length for second children 2

Comment: number of attempt will be >1000, its not necessary every array have 2 elements in it it can vary

Comment: Your desired result is still not clear. Do you want the length of all children arrays to be logged? How are you planning to map as to which log is against which object? A sample response will be really helpful in understanding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will get array length like this:

1st children length

```
console.log(datascource .children.length) // output : 2
```

2nd children length

```
console.log(datascource .children[1].children.length) // output:2
```

3rd children length

```
console.log(datascource .children[1].children[1].children.length) // output : 2
```

4th children length

```
console.log(datascource .children[1].children[1].children[1].children.length) // output : 1
```

Comment: yes you will get like this only datascource .children[1].children[1].children[1].children[1].children.length

Comment: if i have 5000 times array then any optimal solution for that

Comment: @SeemaPatel look for recursive checks then.

Comment: @Jai how i can loop over every children array